# Use Boost-Python in C++ to Access to Array of Functions Defined in Python

Tags: c++, python, boost, python-2.7, boost-python

I have an array of functions in python

```
Func[0](x,y,z)
Func[1](x,y,z)
...
Func[N](x,y,z)
```

How I can load an array of function pointers in c++ by using boost-python get access to the Func[0] to Func[N] in c++.

```
typedef double (*CPP_Function)(double, double, double);
CPP_Function* Funcs; // Array of Function pointers
```

I want to be able to call

```
for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
   a += (*CPP_Function[i])(0,0,0)
```

---

I tried following for 2 functors **with no success**!

```
  Py_Initialize();

  bp::object main_module = bp::import("__main__");
  bp::object main_dict   = main_module.attr("__dict__");

  bp::exec(
    "def f1(x):\n"
    "  return  sin(x)*cos(x)\n"
    "def f2(x):\n"
    "  return  sin(x)*cos(x)\n"
    "f=[f1, f2]",
    main_dict
  );

  bp::object f = main_dict["f"];
  bp::object this_f = f[0];

  std::cout << bp::extract<double>(this_f(1.0)) << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing to me: you have a typedef for function pointers, but you are aware that you will be calling functors. Anyway, the code that you posted doesn't work because you forgot to import math, try with

```
  bp::exec(
    "from math import *\n"
    "def f1(x):\n"
    "  return  sin(x)*cos(x)\n"
    "def f2(x):\n"
    "  return  sin(x)*cos(x)\n"
    "f=[f1, f2]",
    main_dict
  );
```

Then for the c++ type, you might want to use:

```
  typedef std::function<double (double, double, double)> CPP_Function; // (a bad name)
```

Use the standard library, it doesn't bite:

```
  typedef vector< CPP_Function > CPP_Function_vector;
```

And then build an adaptor that constructs CPP_Function objects from python objects. It is extremely easy using lambda functions these days. All together:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>

#include <functional>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
namespace bp = boost::python;

typedef function<double(double, double, double)> CPP_Function;
typedef vector< CPP_Function > CPP_Function_vector; 

CPP_Function_vector convert_functions( bp::object const& functions ) 
{
    int l = bp::len( functions );
    CPP_Function_vector result;
    for (int i=0; i < l; i++ )
    {
        bp::object f = functions[i];
        result.push_back( [f]( double a, double b, double c)->double { return bp::extract<double>(f(a,b,c)); } );
    }
    return result;
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{

    Py_Initialize();

    bp::object main_module = bp::import("__main__");
    bp::object main_dict   = main_module.attr("__dict__");

    bp::exec(
        "from math import *\n"
        "def f1(x,y,z):\n"
        "  return  sin(x)*cos(y)*tan(z)\n"
        "def f2(x,y,z):\n"
        "  return  sin(x)*cos(z)\n"
        "f=[f1, f2]",
        main_dict
    );

    bp::object f = main_dict["f"];

    CPP_Function_vector function_vector = convert_functions( f );

    cout << function_vector[1](1.0, 0.2, 0.3) << endl;

    return 0;

}
```